# I want to put a matrix equation next to a system of equations

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

Hi everyone I am trying to put the matrix equations on the same row space as the system of equations. I am not sure how I tried to put a third `align*` to put the two together but it does not seem to work.

```
\begin{align*} 
\begin{bmatrix}
   1    & 1 & 1  & 0       & 0 & 0\\
   0     & 0 & 0  & 1      & 1 & 1\\
   1      & 0 & 0  & 1      & 0 & 0\\
   0      & 1 & 0  & 0      & 1 & 0\\
   0      & 0 & 1  & 0      & 0 & 1\\
       \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   x_{11}    \\
   x_{12} \\
   x_{13} \\
   x_{21}\\
   x_{22}\\
   x_{23}\\
  \end{bmatrix}
    &=
\begin{bmatrix}
   1    & 1 & 1  & 0       & 0 & 0\\
   0     & 0 & 0  & 1      & 1 & 1\\
   1      & 0 & 0  & 1      & 0 & 0\\
   0      & 1 & 0  & 0      & 1 & 0\\
   0      & 0 & 1  & 0      & 0 & 1\\
       \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   u_{11}    \\
   u_{12} \\
   u_{13} \\
   u_{21}\\
   u_{22}\\
   u_{23}\\
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*} 

\begin{align*} 
x_{11}x_{22}-x_{12}x_{21}&=0 \\
x_{11}x_{22}-x_{12}x_{21}&=0 \\
x_{11}x_{22}-x_{12}x_{21}&=0 \\
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a working document, not just fragments. I am not sure what you want to achieve here actually. What do you mean by `row space`? Shall the `=` of the lower three equations be aligned with the `=` from the matrix equation?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page margins
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'bmatrix' and 'aligned' environments

\begin{document}
\[ 
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 1 & 1  & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0  & 1 & 1 & 1\\
   1 & 0 & 0  & 1 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 1 & 0  & 0 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 1  & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
   x_{11} \\
   x_{12} \\
   x_{13} \\
   x_{21} \\
   x_{22} \\
   x_{23} 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 1 & 1  & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0  & 1 & 1 & 1\\
   1 & 0 & 0  & 1 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 1 & 0  & 0 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 1  & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
   u_{11} \\
   u_{12} \\
   u_{13} \\
   u_{21} \\
   u_{22} \\
   u_{23} 
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad\qquad
\begin{aligned} 
x_{11}x_{22}-x_{12}x_{21}&=0 \\
x_{11}x_{22}-x_{12}x_{21}&=0 \\
x_{11}x_{22}-x_{12}x_{21}&=0 
\end{aligned}
\] 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}


\begin{align*} 
\begin{bmatrix}
   1    & 1 & 1  & 0       & 0 & 0\\
   0     & 0 & 0  & 1      & 1 & 1\\
   1      & 0 & 0  & 1      & 0 & 0\\
   0      & 1 & 0  & 0      & 1 & 0\\
   0      & 0 & 1  & 0      & 0 & 1\\
       \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   x_{11}    \\
   x_{12} \\
   x_{13} \\
   x_{21}\\
   x_{22}\\
   x_{23}\\
  \end{bmatrix}
    &=
\begin{bmatrix}
   1    & 1 & 1  & 0       & 0 & 0\\
   0     & 0 & 0  & 1      & 1 & 1\\
   1      & 0 & 0  & 1      & 0 & 0\\
   0      & 1 & 0  & 0      & 1 & 0\\
   0      & 0 & 1  & 0      & 0 & 1\\
       \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   u_{11}    \\
   u_{12} \\
   u_{13} \\
   u_{21}\\
   u_{22}\\
   u_{23}\\
  \end{bmatrix} \\
x_{11}x_{22}-x_{12}x_{21}&=0 \\
x_{11}x_{22}-x_{12}x_{21}&=0 \\
x_{11}x_{22}-x_{12}x_{21}&=0 \\
\end{align*} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe one of theses solutions?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
   1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
       \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   x_{11} \\
   x_{12} \\
   x_{13} \\
   x_{21}\\
   x_{22}\\
   x_{23}\\
  \end{bmatrix}
    &=
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
   1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
       \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   u_{11} \\
   u_{12} \\
   u_{13} \\
   u_{21}\\
   u_{22}\\
   u_{23}\\
  \end{bmatrix}%
   & \hspace{ 4em}%
  \begin{matrix} x_{11}x_{22}-x_{12}x_{21}=0 \\
  x_{11}x_{22}-x_{12}x_{21}=0 \\
  x_{11}x_{22}-x_{12}x_{21}=0 \\
 \end{matrix}
\end{alignat*}
\vskip1cm
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
   1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
       \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   x_{11} \\
   x_{12} \\
   x_{13} \\
   x_{21}\\
   x_{22}\\
   x_{23}\\
  \end{bmatrix}
    &=
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
   1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
       \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   u_{11} \\
   u_{12} \\
   u_{13} \\
   u_{21}\\
   u_{22}\\
   u_{23}\\
  \end{bmatrix}%
   & \hspace{ 4em}%
  \begin{cases} x_{11}x_{22}-x_{12}x_{21}=0 \\
  x_{11}x_{22}-x_{12}x_{21}=0 \\
  x_{11}x_{22}-x_{12}x_{21}=0 \\
 \end{cases}\hspace{-1em}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]